# Get-CMCategory doesn't work sccm 2012 sp1

Tags: powershell, sccm

I'm trying to work with SCCM 2012 sp1 but few commands are not working.
can anyone please suggest a way around?
below are few of these:

```
Get-CMCategory 
Set-CMDriver  
New-CMVhd 
New-CMCategory          
Add-CMDistributionPoint 
Copy-CMWirelessProfileConfigurationItem
... etc
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the error you are getting since you dont mention it. Do you have the Configuration Manager module loaded? What is the output of the following command: `Get-Command -module ConfigurationManager`?

Comment: @Matt The output of Get-Command is the list of many cmdlets but doesn't contain above cmdlets.

When I run Get-CMCategory, it says
Get-CMCategory : The term 'Get-CMCategory' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-CMCategory
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-CMCategory:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the module loaded? You can see all your options by running the following

`Get-Command -module ConfigurationManager`

If the output is blank its possible that the module is not loaded. I dont know if SCCM installs a special shell that you are supposed to be loading but in a session you could load this:

```
import-module C:\Program Files\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\ConfigurationManager.psd1
```

Substitute your own path to the file for this command to work. Assuming the import works just run this again to see if there is a change `Get-Command -module ConfigurationManager`

Comment: Yes, I had loaded the module.

SCCM 2012 SP1 doesn't have these cmdlets. Can you please suggest a workaround?

Comment: Do you have R2? Get-CMCategory "applies System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager"

Comment: That is precisely the problem, I do not have R2.
There are few cmdlets that work in R2 or as you have phrased it "apply to System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager" but I have to find a workaround so that the functionality provided by these cmdlets can be incorporated in *SCCM 2012 SP1*. 
Custom implementation is also good enough.

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible. Will need someone else to chime in.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, CU4 update was missing.